# WebRTC + Kurento: pause an audio stream to decrease network traffic

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I use Kurento as an MCU for audio conference calls where the users are muted most of the time. When I mute the audio track on the peer side e.g.:

```
track.enabled = false;
```

the network traffic is still generated and the Media Server processes "silence". Is there a way to pause the stream either on the peer or on the Media Server side to decrease the network traffic when the user is not speaking?

**Note:** renegotiation is not an option since it takes to much time for a good user experience.

Thanks.